# Search users on the basis of name and location Facebook Graph API, FQL

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Here's what I am trying to achieve, I have a facebook application which makes use of the search api 
example - https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user

using that I am able to search for users with either their email or name or location, what I also want to do is search on combination of name and location, I also tried fql but that is also not providing the desired result.

Is there a way using FAcebook API to search for people using more than one criteria

Comment: were u able to solve this problem ? i am stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$user_friends1  = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$uid.'/friends?fields=id,name,birthday&access_token='.$access_token);
$user_friends = json_decode($user_friends1,1);
```

now you can find what you want from $user_friends array